# Java switch case statement is returning different type of values(different data-type) and is assigned to same variable of type var

Tags: java, switch-statement, return-type, java-10, yield-return

Following is my code snippet:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = sc.nextInt();

var output = switch (input){
  case 1 -> "one";
  case 2 -> '2';
  case 3 -> 3.14;
  default -> 10;
};

System.out.println(output);
```

Now if I enter 1 as input, it prints "one", for 2 it prints '2', for 3 it prints 3.14 and for the rest it prints 10.

Does this mean datatype of *output* is decided at runtime according to the return type?

Comment: You compiled and executed that code?

Comment: By the way, use try-with-resources syntax to always close your `Scanner`.

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you for speaking my thoughts :D

Comment: By the way, Java 10 is long past end-of-life. I suggest using a [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version: 8, 11, or 17.

Comment: @BasilBourque Updated the code with the one that I compiled and executed. Is the var datatype decided at runtime?

Comment: Do not edit the code so drastically as to change the nature of the question, which your edits did. Instead, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `output` is determined at compile time as something that is `Serializable`, `Comparable` and `Constable`, because that's the closest common ancestor to all of the result.

The object *assigned* to the variable is determined at runtime is one of `String`, `Character`, `Double` or `Integer`.

---

The actual compile type is `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?> & Constable> & Constable` (My IDE told me that!).

Comment: @David Actually, you are correct that it's not `Object`: It's `Serializable`, proved by `Serializable x = output;` compiling. Actually, the type of `var` is `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?> & Constable> & Constable`. See edited answer.

Comment: Again also your edit is not correct! As explained in my answer this is not an `Object` and is not also a `Serializable`. In fact you can't execute the code `output = new ArrayList<String>();` but You could do it defining it as `Serializable`. It happens because `ArrayList` is `Serializable`, but is not `Comparable`

Comment: The correct type is a subclass of Object implementing together Comparable Serializable and Constable

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO not a “subclass” as no such concrete class exists but a *subtype*. An alternative term is *intersection type*.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `output` variable is always determined at compile time as explained [here](https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/guides/lvti-faq#:%7E:text=var%20can%20be%20used%20in,static%20type%20of%20the%20variable.):

> With **var**, the Java compiler **infers the type of the variable at compile time**, using type information obtained from the variable’s initializer. The inferred type is then used as the static type of the variable.

In this particular case, it is a class implementing `Serializable`, `Comparable`, and `Constable` as you can see editing it in a modern ide

[image]

**Note that this is not a generic Object**. Infact you can't reassign the output variable to a generic Object like an ArrayList.

```
output = new ArrayList<String>());    // It doesn't compile
```

while you can reassign to any Comparable Constable and Serializable, for example to a Long

```
output = 10L;    // It compiles!
```

Answer (score 1):

`output` is inferred to the closest common superclass of all of those types, which is the intersection of `Comparable & Serializable`. That's slightly more specific than `Object`, but probably not in a meaningful way in most cases.

Luckily `System.out.println` accepts any old `Object`, since it can `toString()` any possible arguments.

`'2'` is autoboxed to Character, `3.14` to Double and `10` to Integer.

So `output.getClass()` would return one of four distinct things.

Comment: No It is a subclass of Object implementing Comparable, Serializable and Constable. It is not Object

Comment: As explained in my answer you can't do `output = new ArrayList<String>());` but You could do it if you substitute `var` with `Object`, so it is absolutely not an `Object`

Comment: Is not a problem of reassigning variable. But the fact that You can't reassign as explained before means that the type is not a generic Object, but a particular subclass of Object.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Yes, and I edited my answer according, so what's the issue?

Comment: Now the original wrong answer has been corrected. Good